# Any sample Cordova Apps available for visual studio developers

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

i'm new for mobile app development. please post links, sample or any **cordova** apps for **visual studio developers**.

Comment: Any Google research from your side? ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757057.aspx

Comment: but most like for java developers only.. very rare and proper tutorials not available for visual studio developers. i'm looking like using some of plugins, data connections like.

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Comment: so that Stack Overflow will not help for me..

Comment: No, you're trying to use Stack Overflow for something it was not intended for

Comment: You can find VS Cordova samples here 1.) https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-samples 2.) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn848421(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have blank app in Visual Studio. But you can import any cordova app there (but be careful with plugins).
You could check for more corodva templates online, as I know [Ionic has own at least](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-templates-for-visual-studio/).

And yes, your question should be closed.

**EDIT:** I have just checked, Visual Studio 2015 has number templates and samples that uses cordova. But as for me, samples look weird.